# Writing data to online storage through HTTP

Tags: file, http, web, post, storage

Can anyone tell me what is the easiest possible way to write data
by the way of HTTP request to  some online storage (like file)?

For example, the HTTP request would look like this:
https://somesite.net/storage?param=somedatatowrite

This request would be processed, the param "somedatatowrite" extracted and
written to a file/database on that website/storage location.

Later on, another program would read that file and process its content.

I currently have a website "somesite.net" that is hosted on Domain.com
The storage location does not have to be "somesite.net", it can be any location that can be first writtent to through http, and then read from.

I looked into Google Firebase functions, but they look very cumbersome and top-heavy.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you!